# How can I find out if two lines overlap?

Tags: javascript, geometry, boolean-logic

My function takes two objects that represent lines and is supposed to return whether they overlap or not.

Overlapping returns `true`, but not overlapping doesn't seem to return `false`.

Any idea why?

```
function checkOverlap (line1, line2) {
  if (line2.start <= line1.end || line1.start <= line2.end) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check whether one line's start is between the start and end of the other line.

```
  if((line2.start <= line1.end && line2.start >=line1.start) || (line1.start <=line2.end && line1.start >= line2.start)) { 
       return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried your if statement and added an else (else: false). That gives me a "true" result for "overlap", but not a false result for "not overlapping". Do I have to do anything to my else statement?

Comment: I edited. It now checks if the start of one line is between start and end of the other line.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simplest logic that works.

`A.start <= B.end && B.start <= A.end`

It's easy to see why this makes sense if you consider some point, X, that exists in both ranges (assuming an overlap)...

```
A    (start)-------- X --------(end)
B        (start)---- X -------------(end)
```

Imagine pushing the starts and ends around with the requirement that they can't cross X (if it does, then X won't be in both ranges anymore). It becomes pretty easy to see that A start is always before B end and vice versa.

You can tweak `<=` to `<` depending how you want to handle the edges.

```js
console.clear()
let l = console.log

function checkOverlap(A, B){
  return (A.start <= B.end && B.start <= A.end)
}

// Checking All combinations
l(checkOverlap({start: 0, end: 2},{start: 3, end: 5})) // false
l(checkOverlap({start: 0, end: 4},{start: 3, end: 5})) // true
l(checkOverlap({start: 0, end: 6},{start: 3, end: 5})) // true

l(checkOverlap({start: 3, end: 5},{start: 0, end: 2})) // false
l(checkOverlap({start: 3, end: 5},{start: 0, end: 4})) // true
l(checkOverlap({start: 3, end: 5},{start: 0, end: 6})) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure That line2.start lies on line1, but not at the end or line1.start lies on line2 but not at it's end.

```
if ( (line2.start >= line1.start and line2.start < line1.end)
     OR (line1.start >= line2.start and line1.start < line2.end) ) {
    // We have an overlap
}
```