# How can I find out if multiple lines overlap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, function

[image]

Each line segment has 2 xy coordinates given,

Input are below,

[3,4],[5,4]

[8,4],[20,4]

[10,4],[15,4]

In the above picture, **if the lines are overlapping, it can be considered as a line segment**. May I know the logic or mathematics behind solving it which outputs the **2 non-overlapping line segments which are [3,4],[5,4] and [8,4],[20,4]?**

The input I gave is **just 3 line segments** that we have to filter out **to non-overlapping line segments**, so **this gets complicated fast with more line segments if we don't have the proper mathematics**. I am doing this because I faced this bug in my programming :).

I will appreciate any help that I can obtain :)

My solution is I have tried to find whether 2 lines are overlapping from by using some of the logic which is `A.start <= B.end && B.start <= A.end` as stated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076260/how-can-i-find-out-if-two-lines-overlap?fbclid=IwAR3GVF5rU10oTj8izj0evf7aY_xEsED6xPeAqpIeGHM6zb1vRoaWqMQtJmI). The current code which I am stuck on this problem is published in codepen live demo [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/dyjrmKY?editors=0012).

Comment: What if you have a partially overlapping `[2,4],[4,4]` added?

Comment: @PeterThoeny, hi, do you mean if my input becomes 4 line segments which are [3,4],[5,4] , [8,4],[20,4],  [10,4],[15,4] , [2,4],[4,4] ? Then, it should output 2 non-overlapping line segments too which is [2,4],[5,4] and [8,4],[20,4]

Comment: @PeterThoeny, I have scratch my head around this for a long time haha :), so I need some guidance :)

Comment: @PeterThoeny, you can try to imagine if 2 line segment overlap each other and find out what is the overall start and end coordinates, that would be easier :)

Comment: @BuzzSu, One solution is to get the overlapping point of the two lines that contain each line segments and check if each line segment contains that overlapping point.

Comment: @Meerkat, hello, is your solution like the one below too? However, I could not get the correct output from his code? Are there any input mistake that I placed into the function file at https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/dyjrmKY?editors=0011?

Comment: @BuzzSu, no it's something mathematical based on some formular.

Comment: @Meerkat, hi, what is the formula haha :) ? Do you know how to code it out so that you can test the output based on input ?

Comment: @BuzzSu, are all the y coordinates are the same?

Comment: @Meerkat, yes, it is :)

Comment: @Meerkat, have you tried the code by the author below? I could not get proper output from it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed the code and found there was nothing wrong with the logic. The problem was with the dimensions and input.

Here's the revised code.

```
function resolveOverlaps(lines) {
  if (lines.length <= 1) return lines;

  // Sort the lines ascending by start value
  lines.sort((a, b) => a[0][0] - b[0][0]);

  let outLines = [lines[0]];
  let last = outLines[0];
  // Iterate over the lines, skipping the first one
  lines.slice(1).forEach((line) => {
    // There's an overlap, so extend the current segment's end
    if (line[0][0] <= last[1][0]) {
      last[1][0] = Math.max(last[1][0], line[1][0]);
    } else {
      // No overlap, start a new segment
      outLines.push(line);
      last = outLines[outLines.length - 1];
    }
  });
  return outLines;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you try an input which is [[3,4],[5,4]],[[8,4],[20,4]],[[10,4],[15,4]] as stated in my question and run it to see whether the output is correct which is [3,4],[5,4] and [8,4],[20,4] ?

Comment: You need to wrap the input with square brackets once more to make it an array of segments.

Comment: Hello, its me again, after I try a lot of examples with this well-written code, I believe there is a very minor bug in the author's  code, I tested out the code https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/YzjbpLj?editors=0011, in 1D line with all sharing the same line equation, which is [ [[1,2],[6,4]],[[5,3.6],[9,5.2]] , [[12,6.4 ],[16, 8 ]] ], the coordinates for [9,5.2] is replaced with [9,4] on its output which is weird :) How to resolve this :) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your drawing indicates that you're using two-dimensional data points, with x and y coordinates. Finding overlapping lines in 2D requires more sophisticated logic than just checking start and end points.

However, as your sandbox example is 1D, I'll address that.

In this solution, you iterate over each of the line segments, sorted by increasing start coordinate. As you encounter each subsequent segment, you choose to either combine the two or add a new segment, depending on whether they overlap or not.

```js
function resolveOverlaps(lines) {
  if (lines.length <= 1) return lines;
  if (lines[0].length !== 2 || typeof lines[0][0] !== "number") {
    throw new Error(
      "Invalid input shape. resolveOverlaps requires a list of N tuples like `[[start0, end0], ..., [startN, endN]]`"
    );
  }
  for (const line of lines) {
    if (line[0] > line[1]) {
      throw new Error(
        `Invalid segment [${line[0]}, ${line[1]}]. Ensure startend.`
      );
    }
  }

  // Sort the lines ascending by start value
  lines.sort((a, b) => a[0][0] - b[0][0]);

  let outLines = [lines[0]];
  let last = outLines[0];
  // Iterate over the lines, skipping the first one
  lines.slice(1).forEach((line) => {
    // There's an overlap, so extend the current segment's end
    if (line[0][0] <= last[1][0]) {
      last[1][0] = Math.max(last[1][0], line[1][0]);
    } else {
      // No overlap, start a new segment
      outLines.push(line);

      last = outLines[outLines.length - 1];
    }
  });
  return outLines;
}
```

---

**Edit**: Here's an implementation for 2D segments which assumes that all points lie on the same line, and thus only needs to check the x coordinate of each point. A general 2D solution requires more sophisticated logic than this.

```js
function resolveOverlaps2d(lines) {
  if (lines.length <= 1) return lines;
  if (lines[0].length !== 2 || lines[0][0].length !== 2) {
    throw new Error(
      "Invalid input shape. resolveOverlaps requires a list of N tuples like `[[[x0_0, y0_0], [x0_1, y0_1]], ..., [[xN_0, yN_0], [xN_1, yN_1]]]"
    );
  }
  for (const line of lines) {
    if (line[0][0] > line[1][0]) {
      throw new Error(
        `Invalid segment [${line[0]}, ${line[1]}]. Ensure start <= end.`
      );
    }
  }

  // Sort the lines ascending by start value
  lines.sort((a, b) => a[0][0] - b[0][0]);

  let outLines = [lines[0]];
  let last = outLines[0];
  // Iterate over the lines, skipping the first one
  lines.slice(1).forEach((line) => {
    // There's an overlap, so extend the current segment's end
    if (line[0][0] <= last[1][0]) {
      last[1][0] = Math.max(last[1][0], line[1][0]);
    } else {
      // No overlap, start a new segment
      outLines.push(line);

      last = outLines[outLines.length - 1];
    }
  });
  return outLines;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, what is the format for your function input? I tried to test your code at https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/dyjrmKY?editors=0011, ? :) Can you try to run an input and test the output for your code snipplet? :)

Comment: I have tried console.log(resolveOverlaps([[3,4],[5,4]],[[8,4],[20,4]],[[10,4],[15,4]])    );, but does not get the correct output which are   [3,4],[5,4] and [8,4],[20,4]?

Comment: Hi, can you please reply? :)

Comment: As I mentioned, my solution is implemented for 1D points, meaning that the inputs should be a list of `[start, end]` tuples, like `[[3, 6], [2, 4], [11, 19]]`. Can I ask the purpose of the additional "4" in each of your values?

Comment: Hi, I believe there is a very minor bug in your code, I tested out your code https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/YzjbpLj?editors=0011, in 1D line with all sharing the same line equation, which is [    [[1,2],[6,4]],[[5,3.6],[9,5.2]] , [[12,6.4 ],[16, 8 ]]        ], the coordinates for [9,5.2] is replaced with [9,4] on its output which is weird :) How to resolve this :) ?

Comment: Again, my implementation is for 1D points. I've added some input validation to ensure that you provide data of the right shape. I've also added another implementation that supports 2D points, but on the assumption that they all lie on the same line. With this assumption, we can assume that looking at x-values only is sufficient to resolve overlaps. A general 2D solution is much more complicated as it essentially requires separating segments into those that line on the same line.